# RedGate shows percents instead of milliseconds

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, redgate

I tried to compare RedGate performance profile on two different machines and to my surprise the on one RedGate shows milliseconds but no code text (there is no source) and on another it shows code text with percentage against worked lines.

How can I see milliseconds?

P.S. I am sure I picked Wall Clock in settings on both machines.

Comment: Try asking on their forums: http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewforum.php?f=100

Comment: yeah I already got an answer from there.. I was just waiting that someone else will answere here so I dont answer my own questions all the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is apparently in *View* menu *Seconds* option